# Sign out of all subdomains using IdentityServer 4

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have an application that has multiple subdomains - for example, portal.mysite.com, admin.mysite.com, etc. - and they all use auth.mysite.com, which is running IdentityServer 4. The main site is using React with oidc-client-js, and the whole thing is set up for implicit flow. When the site transitions between subdomains, I call oidcUserManager.signinSilent() before loading the rest of the app to ensure the user is logged in.

This all works great. Logging out, however, doesn't work. If I logout from www.mysite.com then go back to www.mysite.com, I'm logged out. But if I logout from www.mysite.com then open portal.mysite.com, the silent authentication succeeds. I am calling logout with:

```
const id_token_hint = user.id_token
oidcUserManager.signoutRedirect({ id_token_hint })
```

This properly redirects me to the logout page, where I've added a ton of redundant calls:

```
var vm = await _account.BuildLoggedOutViewModelAsync(model.LogoutId);
await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityServerConstants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme);
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
```

My understanding is that, if the cookie that IdentityServer uses is destroyed, the user should be logged out across everything. As browser security properly works, I cannot clear the oidc keys from browser storage across all the possible subdomains they may have visited.

I've played with cookie authentication schemes, none made a difference. I've manually deleted all the cookies, same issue. I've also used the interaction service to manually revoke all tokens for the session, and I still get logged in just fine.

I admit, I don't fully understand the back channel/front channel stuff, but the issue I'm trying to solve here is all within one tab - the app isn't running in the browser at the time of log out. I suppose it could be, but that's for later! I think?

Any suggestions on how I might log the user out of all the subdomains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working with reference tokens, which I can fully revoke, as opposed to JWTs which I cannot. As I've learned more about these specs, this is the way I should have gone in the first place!

Comment: Can you provide details on how you got around this issue? A sample perhaps?

Comment: I do not have a full working sample, but I injected `IIdentityServerInteractionService` into my controller, and the logout method does the following, in addition to _signInManager.SignOutAsync():

            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityServerConstants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme);
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();

            await _interaction.RevokeTokensForCurrentSessionAsync();